# Cauchy-Goursat's theorem and residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, greens-theorem

I am a little bit confused about using these theorems. For example, if I want to find the value of $\int_C e^{az}/z dz$ given that C is the unit circle with positive orientation, and a is a real number.

Without knowing that if z is inside the circle or outside the circle, does that mean I can't use any of this theorem?

And if I want to use these theorems, first I need to prove that the function is analytic and second its interior is inside the contour? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What matters is if $0$ is inside or outside the circle $C$.  That's becuse $0$ is the only singularity of your function $e^{ax}/z$.

Comment: Is it because C is the unit circle, what if C is not the unit circle? How do we proceed questions like this?

Comment: pick a simple enough contour. Any simple contour will work but why make it harder when a circle is the easiest?